# How to open a port for the public ip address in Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: macos, network

I see that I can find the public IP address for my MBP using

[Current IP Address](http://www.ipchicken.com/)

I wish to open a port in my machine to run a servlet. I see a link

[How to open a port in MBP](https://gauravsohoni.wordpress.com/2015/04/14/mac-osx-open-port/)

However, when I open the port, run the flask based service in the port and check if the service is visible,

```
<public IP Address>:<Port Number>/service?file=<file>
```

I get

> This page isn’t working
>
> *IP Address* didn’t send any data.
>
> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

I wish to know how to make a service accessible to the web from my machine with an open port.

Comment: Are you trying to use port 80 for a web page? Or something else?

Comment: How is your Mac connected to the internet? Is there a router or such inbetween? Is the port open on the router and does traffic on this port get forwarded to your Mac?

Comment: Also, instead of referring to a documentation on how to open a port, can you please add the relevant part of your pf.conf directly to the question. And can you try accessing it locally with `localhost`/`127.0.0.1` as the IP address?

Comment: The mac is connected using a router. How do I open the port? When I check with Network Utility, it says the port is not open with the public IP address. I wish to use the service from another machine. so cannot use localhost.

Comment: You have to find the user guide for your router, in there you’ll be able to find some kind of a guide explaining how to enable port forwarding. If your ISP is using a NAT, this won’t work...

Comment: I have a Time Capsule router and enabled the port forwarding with DHCP and NAT. However, when I check the port using Network Utility, it says it is not open for the IP address in the router.